# When checkbox is checked, item is added to list, when 2nd box is checked both 1st item and 2nd item are added to list?

Tags: vb.net

Receiving introductory programming lectures in VB studio 2013.
  I decided to try out a list box for myself on the side and having difficulty coding it, here is the code I have:

Toppingsselected = This is the name for the list box

Pepperoni = name for the check box

Ham = name for the 2nd check box

```
Private Sub Small_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pepperoni.CheckedChanged, Ham.CheckedChanged

      If Pepperoni.Checked = True Then
            toppingsselected.Items.Add("Pepperoni")
        Else
            toppingsselected.Items.Remove("Pepperoni")
        End If
        If Ham.Checked = True Then
            toppingsselected.Items.Add("Ham")
        Else
            toppingsselected.Items.Remove("Ham")
        End If
End Sub
```

Basically, when check and uncheck "pepperoni", it adds and removes "pepperoni" text to and from the list box, but when I check "Ham" it adds pepperoni and ham to the list box.

Apologies if I'm not down with the lingo, just a beginner here, if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong I'd be grateful

Comment: You have the same code for both handlers.  Separate them into different methods.  Or inspect the sender object to see which checkbox control is causing the event, and only act on that one.

Comment: Your sub is going to be executed every time you check or uncheck each of checkboxes. When you check ham then it will run code. In the first if it controles the state of first checkbox and it is checked, so it pushes peperoni text into listbox. Then it continues to see if second checkbox is checked and this is true also so adds the ham text also to listbox.

Comment: you could also just cleari the listbox right before your first IF statement. However, if other code manipulates this listbox doing so will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you given same event for two controls, it fires for both controls checked event, just use the following code, I hope it works.

```
Private Sub Small_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Pepperoni.CheckedChanged, Ham.CheckedChanged
 If sender.Name = "Pepperoni" Then
  If Pepperoni.Checked = True Then
        toppingsselected.Items.Add("Pepperoni")
    Else
        toppingsselected.Items.Remove("Pepperoni")
    End If
End If
If sender.Name = "Ham" Then
    If Ham.Checked = True Then
        toppingsselected.Items.Add("Ham")
    Else
        toppingsselected.Items.Remove("Ham")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```